# xamarin form : posting jarray null values to web api

Tags: xamarin.forms, asp.net-web-api2

i am posting jarray to to webapi, but its posting null values here is my code

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


                    JArray paramList = new JArray();

                        paramList.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contactDetail));




                        paramList.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_LocalNote));


                        paramList.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_InvoiceDetail));


                        paramList.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Invoice));

                        paramList.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_Customer_Files));




                        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://afboilersolutions.com/api/ContactDetails", paramList.Values()).Result;
```

i dont know where is wronng in this code

WebApi

```
public IHttpActionResult PostContactDetail(JObject paramLlist)
        {


            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            if (paramLlist[0] != null)
            {
                contactDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContactDetail>(paramLlist[0].ToString());
            }
            if (paramLlist[1] != null)
            {
                notes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Note>>(paramLlist[1].ToString());
            }
            if (paramLlist[2] != null)
            {
                invoiceDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<InvoiceDetail>>(paramLlist[2].ToString());
            }
            if (paramLlist[3] != null)
            {
                invoices = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Invoice>>(paramLlist[3].ToString());
            }
            if (paramLlist[4] != null)
            {
                files = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer_Files>>(paramLlist[4].ToString());
            }
```

i am getting data from xamarin side which i am postin, but in web api i am recieiving null jarray

Comment: have you looked at paramList.Values() to verify what it is sending?

Comment: i have check and i am getting all data in paramList.Values() which i am sending, but i am not recieving in webapi

Comment: What does your webapi method look like?

Comment: i have added code above

Comment: your WebAPI method accepts a **JObject**, you are passing it **JArray.Values()**